# entityManager.persist(user) -> javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: User@b3089 is already persistent

Tags: java, spring, orm, jpa, persistence

```
// lookup existing user & set a currently null child entity (ContactInfo)
user.setContactInfo(contactInfo);

// update the user in the datastore with newly created child Entity             
entityManager.persist(user);
```

Generates exception:

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: User@b3089 is already persistent
```

Since the user already exists, is there some other method besides `entityManager.persist` that I should be using for an update instead of an insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `user` instance is already loaded in the persistence context, just modifiy it and **don't** invoke any `EntityManager` method, the JPA provider will automatically update the database at flush or commit time.

Answer (score 2):

What about `entityManager.merge(user)`?

Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge).