# best approach for updation using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

Using JPA which method should I follow while updating?

approach 1

```
obj o = new obj()
o.setName('val')
set other values
entitymanger.merge(ibj)
```

approach 2

```
obj o = getObjFromDb(obj)
obj.setval(name)
//not am not updating other attributes

entitymanage.merge(obj)
```

Comment: Please not that getObjFrommDB starts and ends transcation by itself

Answer (score 4):

You really need to understand the semantics of the `merge` operation so I'll repeat what the JPA spec is saying:

> #### 3.2.4.1 Merging Detached Entity State
>
> The merge operation allows for the
>   propagation of state from detached
>   entities onto persistent entities
>   managed by the EntityManager.
>
> The semantics of the merge operation
>   applied to an entity X are as follows:
>
> - If X is a detached entity, the state of X is copied onto a pre-existing
>     managed entity instance X' of the same
>     identity or a new managed copy X' of X
>     is created.
> - If X is a new entity instance, a new managed entity instance X' is created
>     and the state of X is copied into the
>     new managed entity instance X'.
> - If X is a removed entity instance, an `IllegalArgumentException` will be
>     thrown by the merge operation (or the
>     transaction commit will fail).
> - If X is a managed entity, it is ignored by the merge operation,
>     however, the merge operation is
>     cascaded to entities referenced by
>     relationships from X if these
>     relationships have been annotated with
>     the cascade element value
>     `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL`
>     annotation.
> - For all entities Y referenced by relationships from X having the
>     cascade element value `cascade=MERGE` or
>     `cascade=ALL`, Y is merged recursively
>     as Y'. For all such Y referenced by
>     X, X' is set to reference Y'. (Note
>     that if X is managed then X is the
>     same object as X'.)
> - If X is an entity merged to X', with a reference to another entity Y, where
>     `cascade=MERGE` or `cascade=ALL` is
>     not specified, then navigation of the
>     same association from X' yields a
>     reference to a managed object Y' with
>     the same persistent identity as Y.
>
> The persistence provider must not
>   merge fields marked LAZY that have not
>   been fetched: it must ignore such
>   fields when merging.
>
> Any `Version` columns used by the
>   entity must be checked by the
>   persistence runtime implementation
>   during the merge operation and/or at
>   flush or commit time. In the absence
>   of `Version` columns there is no
>   additional version checking done by
>   the persistence provider runtime
>   during the merge operation.

In other words, the `merge` operation copies the state of the passed entity to a **managed** entity with the same database identity (that will be loaded in the persistence context if necessary) and then returns a reference to that **managed** entity (and the object passed is not attached to the persistence context).

Back to the initial question now. In both case, the database values will be overridden with the full state of the passed entity, including non null (and null) values. In practice:

- approach 2 i.e. working directly on detached entities is easier
- approach 1 sounds like the DTO anti pattern and means more pain

Prefer approach 2 if you can.

#### Related question

- [JPA EntityManager: Why use persist() over merge()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge)

Answer (score 2):

You first approach creates new object, so **merge** wouldn't update object, but place new one into DB. So approach 2 is look better. But looking at you comment about getObjFromDb about transaction, I have to note that methods: **merge**, **persist**, **remove** should be done inside transaction scope.

So better solution pseudo-code is:

```
boolean transactionClosed = false;
entitymanage.getTransaction().begin();
try{
   obj o = entitymanage.find( someKey );
   o.setval(name);
   entitymanage.getTransaction().commit();
   transactionClosed = true;
}
finally{
   if( !transactionClosed )
       entitymanage.getTransaction().rollback();
}
```

Comment: ...or better say approach 2 looks the only approach. +1

Comment: @akp - I made accent that **merge** - must be used for update only, but not for creation new object in database.

Comment: This is incorrect, merging a NEW entity doesn't throw an exception (and anyway, I'm assuming the OP is setting the database identifier so it's actually a detached entity).

Comment: @Dewfy Sorry but merge can create a new entity: JPA is clear: If X is a new entity instance, **a new managed entity instance X is created** and the state of X is copied into the new managed entity instance X.