# What are the differences between Hibernate Session methods saveOrUpdate() and merge()?

Tags: java, hibernate

What are the differences between [Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/) [Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html) methods [saveOrUpdate(Object)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#saveOrUpdate(java.lang.Object)) and [merge(Object)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#merge(java.lang.Object))?  It seems that both methods generate an [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) [INSERT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL)) statement when the given object does not exist in the corresponding table and an [UPDATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_(SQL)) when it does exist.

Comment: Did you actually read the java docs you linked to? :)

Comment: Yes, I did.  The main difference that I see is that `merge()` loads an object that is not in the session while `saveOrUpdate()` does not.  Does this mean that `saveOrUpdate()` of a partial object overwrites all fields while `merge()` overwrites only those fields that have been set to non-null values?  Or do both produce the same result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NHibernate - Difference between session.Merge and session.SaveOrUpdate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170962/nhibernate-difference-between-session-merge-and-session-saveorupdate)

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is for NHibernate, it also applies to Hibernate:

[NHibernate - Difference between session.Merge and session.SaveOrUpdate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170962/nhibernate-difference-between-session-merge-and-session-saveorupdate)

Comment: According to the third comment, NHibernate `Merge()` and `SaveOrUpdate()` produce exactly the same result.  (The commenter states that `SaveOrUpdate()` simply delegates to `Merge()`.)

Comment: Ok, if this is true, than it's not the same for Hibernate :-) Both calls *may* produce the same result, but depends on the state of the entity. Instead of replicating the documentation, I'll provide just the updated link :-) http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-saveorupdate

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, merge is for un-associated instances, that aren't currently managed.  It will do a lookup based on id and merge the two.

Comment: What does it mean to "merge the two" objects?  How does it know which fields to merge?  Does it merge only those that do not differ or those that differ and are non-null?  The first case is no different from an update while the second differs from both save and update.

Comment: Look at the second answer on the linked question that quotes the spec. 3.2.4.1 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870844/best-approach-for-updation-using-jpa  It looks like the detached instance will overwrite most of the data, unless a field is marked lazy or the class supports versions.

Answer (score 1):

[SaveOrUpdate versus Merge in Hibernate](http://www.stevideter.com/2008/12/07/saveorupdate-versus-merge-in-hibernate/) explains the differences between `saveOrUpdate()` and `merge()`.