# What happens when I merge an object in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

In my project, some time I have to load a object to edit them.
Before this, I think, hibernate session is closed.

Some time before save the edited object (with `saveOrUpdate`), I have to search (open session again) for a object in the database, and, maybe, the object returned by this search is the object I'll update. (I need this object for some validations and other things...)

After this, when I try to save the object, hibernate says that I have another object with the same identifier in the session.

I have implemented my own `equals` and `hashcode` methods, and I tried to do somethings, like `session.evict(object)`, but, nothing works.

So, I use `session.merge(object)` instead of `session.saveOrUpdate(object)`, and it works.
But, I dont know exactly what is the consequences of doing this. I can simple replace `saveOrUpdate` by `merge`, or I will get some issues with it? Another thing I have to know about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this is a duplicate for [What are the differences between Hibernate Session methods saveOrUpdate() and merge()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462412/what-are-the-differences-between-hibernate-session-methods-saveorupdate-and-me)
and a number of other questions, very common question indeed...

Comment: yeah, maybe. But, I still dont understand what exactly merge do. Like, "yeah, it merge the objects", but, if the name of a Person object, for example, is "Carlos", and I updated it to "jambriz", what of them will be persisted, and why? Other thing, what happens with the cascades?