# Why cannot I use persist in a object which has been taken from database?

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo, entitymanager, persist

I thought that I can do persist using the method persist of entitymanager in my objects of spring. Actually I use spring roo. But when I take a object from database I cannot do it:

```
object.persist(); // <--- it doesn't work
```

Do anyone know why? and where can I find the documentation?

I'm getting this exception:

```
 org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.movi.duckury.server.domain.LoginLog; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.movi.duckury.server.domain.LoginLog
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:311)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:15)
at com.movi.duckury.server.domain.LoginLog_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethod$com_movi_duckury_server_domain_LoginLog_Roo_Entity$com_movi_duckury_server_domain_LoginLog$persist(LoginLog_Roo_Entity.aj:54)
at com.movi.duckury.server.domain.LoginLog.persist(LoginLog.java:1)
at com.movi.duckury.server.domain.LoginLog_Roo_Entity.ajc$interMethodDispatch1$com_movi_duckury_server_domain_LoginLog_Roo_Entity$com_movi_duckury_server_domain_LoginLog$persist(LoginLog_Roo_Entity.aj)
at com.movi.duckury.server.web.LoginLogControllerTest.findLoginLogsBySessionIdTest(LoginLogControllerTest.java:101)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.movi.duckury.server.domain.LoginLog
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1214)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1153)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:678)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor21.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy54.persist(Unknown Source)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.movi.duckury.server.domain.LoginLog
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:808)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:782)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:786)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:672)
    ... 39 more

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting an Exceptions, or it's just not persisting?

Comment: In general you should try to provide as much relevant data/code as possible. Try providing code for your entity object and any error stacktraces in order for us to isolate any errors.

Answer (score 3):

Because it ie already persisted. A primary key conflict will occur, basically.

Use `object.merge()` (if I recall correctly the name of the method created by Roo)

Stefano

Comment: I believe the actual exception thrown is because the object is detached in this case (although it means that it is persisted as well). At any rate merge() will take care of it.

Comment: Why is dettached? I have a problem... very strange. When I run the tests, if I load different application context in different test, this fail. I don't know why.

Comment: For example if I do @ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext1.xml")
and  @ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext2.xml") and applicationContext2 import applicationContext1 this fail

Comment: Does the second context contain something more than the import?

Comment: it has a contex:component-scan to get the controllers as beans and in this way to do @autowire.

Comment: does it throw an exception or is it the test that fails? can you post the reason of the error?

Comment: When I run individual tests, this works and when I run all the test toguether fails. There are differents errors, like detached entity passed to persist or violationException: could not insert or could not execute query. Every error is in different tests

Comment: Sounds like you're persisting the same entity sevaral times. Try mark all your tests with `@Transactional` and `@Rollback(true)`. This should allow you to run every test in a clean environment. This is only a guess, hope will help you.

Comment: I got to solve :), I created a new question for this: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547767/jpa-problems-running-multiple-tests-with-spring[/link] thanks @Stefano

Answer (score 1):

[JPA EntityManager: Why use persist() over merge()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge)

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/store