# jpa problems running multiple tests with spring

Tags: spring, testing, jpa, junit

my problem is that when I run tests individually the test work properly but when I run all the tests several tests start to fail.

It looks to be a problem of the applicationContext I have 3 applicationContext but the applicationContext-test import the 2 before.

Some times I do 
@applicationContext(applicatonContext1.xml)

and other times
@applicationContext(applicationContext-test.xml)

I get different exceptions for different tests:

- SQLGrammarException: could not execute query.
- Detached entity exceptions
- ConstraintViolation exception.

Some tests work properly and some no, but I don't know why. 
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run all JUnit tests indepentently in Eclipse, reloading Spring context each time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854527/run-all-junit-tests-indepentently-in-eclipse-reloading-spring-context-each-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put`DirtiesContext` on test to allow context to be reloaded each time you run test.

Different `@ApplicationContext` should work fine. I think you not clean the database in your test (because without `@DirtiesContext` spring will use same context (and same DB) for same  `@ApplicationContext`).

Comment: Ok that seems that worked. but now I'm getting other exception in the test generated by roo. IllegalStateException: Entity manager has not been injected. And if I run the test individually this work properly

Comment: Please provide test class annotation

Comment: I use @RooIntegrationTest(entity = employee.class).  It doesn't fail when I do mvn test, only fail in eclipse

Comment: I have just used @DirtiesContext in the generated roo tests too and this works!. No errors Thanks very much!