# JUnit - @DirtyContext not reset neo4j database after each test method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, unit-testing, junit

I'm using `Spring 4.3.3.RELEASE`, `Hibernate 5.0.11.Final`, `JUnit 4.1.2`, `SDN4.1.3-RELEASE` and `neo4j-ogm-2.0.5`. I read and try to implement `@DirtyContext` that can reset my Database after each test method finish running. But When I look at my Database, All nodes that i created in Test method still there.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MockApplication.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode=ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class OrderServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @Autowired
    private TableService tableService;

    @Test
    public void orderMenuFoodAndDrink() throws Exception {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setName("Customer 1");
        customerService.save(customer);

        Table table = new Table ();
        table.setCustomer(customer);
        tableService.save(table);

        ObjectResult result = orderService.orderTable(customer.getId());

        assertThat(result.getTables().get(0), is(table`enter code here`));
    }
}
```

And this is How I set my Configuration Context with Java Annotation

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public OrderService OrderService() {
        OrderService OrderService = new OrderServiceImpl();
        return OrderService;
    }
}
```

`OrderService` is my Interface Class, and `OrderServiceImpl` is my Service Implementation. I have two references, but all of those is not working, because when I look at my database, all nodes still there, not deleted

1. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14343893/how-do-i-reset-my-database-state-after-each-unit-test-without-making-the-whole-t)
2. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24854527/run-all-junit-tests-indepentently-in-eclipse-reloading-spring-context-each-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `@Transactional` annotation to your test class

```
@Transactional
public class OrderServiceTest
```

Comment: Oh My.. I miss this one.. Thank you @Jobin

Comment: And for Information, I do not need ContextConfiguration, just use Transactional and DirtyContext, already work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try @DirtiesContext with classMode

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
```

Comment: I also try this before, it gave same problem, all database data after test still remain.