# EJB Entity will not refresh from EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

So I'm developing a webapp and Im attempting to use JPA in order to access my database. I grab entities from my database using an EJB however, if I get another instance from the EJB and make changes to that, the changes are not reflected in my old entity. Moreover when I try to refresh my old entity, I get an error stating the entity is not managed. I can devise a work around, I was just wondering what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks as follows.

EJB + JPA lives in a EJB container. Your Web application lives in a Web application container. Both containers are part of application server, but they communicate as if Web Containter was just a EJB components client.

So, basically, you have typical client (Web app) - server (EJB + JPA) scenario.

Now, if you bring entity from EJB to client side it does not know about changes made on the server - it is just normal object that you have on the client side (it "forgets" its EJB/JPA origin). That's why you don't see any changes in the web application, even though you are changing analogus entity in EJB container.

You must synchronize your client side object and the one kept in EJB container manually.

The second problem - entity is not managed. When you send entity from client side to EJB container, then EJB container does not make any assumptions about that entity - it treats it as a normal object.

In order to tell EJB container "hey, look, that entity is not just some random object, it is entity I want YOU to manage", you need to call on that object `EntityManager.merge(entity)` method before doing any further actions.

This method adds entity to persistent context cache and returns object that is attached to entity manager session.

That's important! You need to modify right object

```
Object addedToEM = EntityManager.merge(entity)
```

If you want to make any updates on the server side, you need to modify addedToEM entity (see for instance [JPA EntityManager: Why use persist() over merge()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge) for good explanation).