# JPA detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a DAO with `@Transactional` annotation and with `EntityManager` inside.

Also I have a some IOC managed bean that has one transactional method inside.

And there are 2 entities with uni directional many2one -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AU_EVENT")
public class AuEvent { 
    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = "MODULE_ID")
private AuModule auModule;
}
```

AuModule doesnt have reference on `AuEvents`

I'm trying to do like this

```
@Async
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void onEvent(String moduleName, String instanceName){
        AuModule auModule = auModuleDao.findModule(moduleName, instanceName);
        if (auModule == null) {
            auModule = new AuModule();
            auModule.setInstance(instanceName);
            auModule.setName(moduleName);
        }
//doesnt help
//auModule = auModuleDao.getEntityManager().merge(auModule);

AuEvent auEvent = new AuEvent();
auEvent.setAuModule(auModule);
auEventDao.persist(auEvent); // error here [AuModule detached]
}
```

As I read in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057333/detached-entity-passed-to-persist-error-with-onetomany-relation I tried to do in this way

```
@Async
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void onEvent(String moduleName, String instanceName){

    AuEvent auEvent = new AuEvent();
    auEventDao.persist(auEvent);

    AuModule auModule = auModuleDao.findModule(moduleName, instanceName);
    if (auModule == null) {
        auModule = new AuModule();
        auModule.setInstance(instanceName);
        auModule.setName(moduleName);
    }
    auEvent.setAuModule(auModule);
    auEventDao.persist(auEvent); // error here [AuEvent detached]
}
```

SO, does anyone know how I can avoid this?
PS Please don't suggest me to write DAO method like that -

```
public void saveEvent(AuEvent auEvent, String moduleName, String instanceName){
    log.info("saveEvent({}) called...", auEvent);
    AuModule auModule = auModuleDao.findModule(moduleName, instanceName);
    if (auModule == null) {
        auModule = new AuModule();
        auModule.setInstance(instanceName);
        auModule.setName(moduleName);
    }
    auEvent.setAuModule(auModule);
    persist(auEvent);
}
```

I exactly want to save event&module not inside of any DAO

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example, you should not call `auEventDao.persist(auEvent);` in the end. `auEvent` is already *attached* so its enough that your transaction just ends.
Also you **shouldn't** call `persist()` on object which is allready persistent. You should call it only on new objects. That's also the problem in your first example.

You call `persist()` only once on `auEvent` that's right. But sometimes there's existing (already persisted, found in DB) `auModule` associated with this `auEvent`. And you marked this association with `CascadeType.PERSIST`. So `persist()` is cascaded also to existing `auModule` -> **exception thrown**.

Something like this should work:
1.

```
@Async
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void onEvent(String moduleName, String instanceName){
        AuModule auModule = auModuleDao.findModule(moduleName, instanceName);
        if (auModule == null) {
            auModule = new AuModule();
            auModule.setInstance(instanceName);
            auModule.setName(moduleName);
        }
       AuEvent auEvent = new AuEvent();
       auEventDao.persist(auEvent); 

       auEvent.setAuModule(auModule);
       auEventDao.merge(auEvent);
}
```

or
2.

```
@Async
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void onEvent(String moduleName, String instanceName){

    AuEvent auEvent = new AuEvent();
    auEventDao.persist(auEvent);

    AuModule auModule = auModuleDao.findModule(moduleName, instanceName);
    if (auModule == null) {
        auModule = new AuModule();
        auModule.setInstance(instanceName);
        auModule.setName(moduleName);
    }
    auEvent.setAuModule(auModule);
    // optioanlly you can call here - auEventDao.merge(auEvent); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me! But the only one difference i see between 1 and 2 - is the call of DAO.merge()... I can't believe that if I didn't call merge (2nd variant) auModule would be saved into DB...

Comment: It should work, auEvent entity is *attached* see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge . I would rather prefer first option, explicitly calling merge.

Comment: @OndrejBozek It would be nice if the provider were smart enough to do the persist then do the merge.

Answer (score 0):

In the onEvent() method you did not set the AuModule in the AuEvent after the if as you did in the saveEvent() method.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry it's my mistake - i didn't write it because i had to moderate my code - it's a commercial projetc. I apologizez again.