# Parent Object insert into two times when Child object inserted

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

In my Hibernate Application i have Timetable(parent) classtable(child) is their.

My first operation is insert into Timetable and using this timetable many classtable inserted. Like onetomany Relation.

But i'm facing the Problem : first Timetable inserted and classtable inserted and again timetable and classtable..........so on..

But my intention is only one Timetable and Many classtable.

Hear is my Code...in Timetable

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "timetable",cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<ClassTableVO> classtable;
```

And ClassTable

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_TABLE_ID")
    private TimetableVO timetable;
```

And if we remove `(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})` it give Exception like `object references an unsaved transient instance`
 Please help me..

```
Edit:
```

In my Hibernate i'm using JPA EntityManager class

```
userDAO.createEvent(timetableVO);//this loop only one time executed 
------
-----
for(---){
userDAO.createClassTable(classTable);
}
```

and above method have two line of code in both two methods..

```
entityManager.merge(classTable);//
entityManager.flush();
```

Comment: post your code when you want to save

Comment: Actually i'm Using JPA EntityManager class so i'm using Merge() method..

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge) a discussion about marge() and persist(); maybe you need to persist() instead of merging

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `TimeTableVO.addClassTable(ClassTableVO ct)` remember to set `ClassTableVO.timetable`:

```
public void TimeTableVO.addClassTable(ClassTableVO ct){
  if(classtable.add(ct)){
    ct.setTimetable(this);
  }
}
```

so link are correctly setter and Hibernate know ho to correctly cascade object while saving