# jpa: when merging many to many previous record gets deleted

Tags: rest, jpa, ejb, many-to-many, eclipselink

i have a Users and Tags table,and also a user_tag_xref table that holds the many to many relationship.now netbeans generates the entity classes for me (using eclipselink) below is the entity mapping relationship

on User class

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "usersList")
    private List<Tags> tagsList;
```

on Tags class

```
@JoinTable(name = "USERS_TAG_XREF", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "TAG_ID", referencedColumnName = "TAG_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")})
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Users> usersList;
```

Now im my business logic RESTfull service,a json client consumes this method

```
 @POST
    @Path("/registration2/tag") 
     @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response registration2_3(List<Tags>tagList,@Context HttpServletRequest req){

         Profile p =(Profile) registerMap.get(req.getSession().getId());
     Users u = em.find(Users.class,p.getUserId());


    for(Tags t : tagList){
        t.getUsersList().add(u);
        u.getTagsList().add(t); 
        em.merge(t);
        em.merge(u); 

    }     
   logger.log(Level.INFO, "the taglist created for user");

       return Response.ok(u,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build(); 
    }
```

The problem is each time i merge a new user to create a many to many relationship, if an existing userid=6201 has a tag with 2,3,4 ,and the new user is try to use to tag id 2,3,4,
the existing user is deleted and the new user merges to the tags. i have read several articles on overriding hash and equals to method in my entity classes,those methods are overridden by default in eclipselink ,also i cannot change my collection type to Set or Collection since List<> type works perfectly well for a json array. i v been having a hard time right now,its been 24hours,could it be the default mapping strategy is wrong? do i need to cascasde?

Comment: can anybody please help if you are viewing? please

Comment: What is in the t.getUserList() when you call merge on it?  Where is t and the tagList coming from?  As is stated, you have to be careful that the tag actually reflects what you want in the database when you call merge.  If it is only partially complete, you are overwriting complete data with partial data.  Also, what is getting deleted, is it just the references in the join table?

Comment: Good question by Chris. Is the reference in join table deleted ?

Comment: t.getUserList() contains (one user) a user_id 6201 who has 3 tags_id 1,2,3 in one to many relationship, t and tagList is coming from a json array,i can read the arrays perfectly well, but with the code mr shailendra wrote, if a new user_id 6202 uses the post method sending tagList with tag_id 1,2,3, user_id 6202 will have 1,2,3 thereby deleting user 6201 from the db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be extra cautious while using merge as its semantics ( as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge?lq=1)) is bit different from just update.
As your relationship is bidirectional and users is the inverse side, so all of relationship persistence will be handled by
tags side. Assuming that you tag lists contains detached tags, meaning all Tags have their id set, then you need to iterate over tagList

```
Tag managedTag = em.merge(t);
```

This takes care that if t is new instance (unmanaged) then a persistent representation of it will be returned
which has to be used there after or if the instances were having their id set, then the ORM will create a managed instance with data from database ( or from first/second level cache if it exists there). The returned instance is the one managed

```
for(Tags t : tagList){
        Tag managedTag = em.merge(t);
        managedTag.getUsersList().add(u);
        u.getTagsList().add(t);         
       User managedUser =  em.merge(u); 

    }
```

Also you can set the Merge cascade option on the Tag side to save you the second merge call and let the ORM manage relationship automatically.

Comment: i tried your code and it still gives me the same result, i modified your code thinking maybe the managed tag needed to be added to the            u.getTagList().add(managedTag);

Comment: replace em.merge(t) with em.find(Tags.class, t.getId()) and see if this resolves the issue.

Comment: whooaaaaa,i replaced it with em.find(Tags.class,tgetId()) and it worked, please why did it work? isnt the merged from  Tag managedTag = em.merge(t); not actually merging it to a managed state?

Comment: I tried pointing out the problem by asking where your tags come from.  If they are not complete entities, you are merging this incomplete data overtop of your complete managed entities.  This is a problem when applications try to use stubs and only set the ID rather than an em.find/getReference to get the actual data.  Merge will overwrite the entity data with the unpopulated null fields.  Using find works because you then modify the full entity with only the changes you want, rather than with what ever is in the stub.

Comment: As pointed by Chris, merge needs to be used carefully as in majority of cases the detached entity typically recieved from the front end is 
not complete in terms of relations and merge takes those relations in consideration. Due to this in most of cases, people tend to merge the data 
themselves instead of relying on JPA merge (DIY pattern). I have read to the extent books advising not to use merge at all (e.g, seam in action).
The idiom goes like this. You first load the entity in persistent context and then update its state by manually
copying over.Similar for the relations.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how merge behaves with detached entities and relations.

```
@Entity
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int        id;

    private String     name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList();
.......................
}


@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int       id;

    private String    name;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="users",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList();
........................
}
```

TestProgram

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Test");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

User user = new User();
user.setName("User");
User managedUser = em.merge(user);
int userId = managedUser.getId();
//create a tag        
Tag tag = new Tag();
tag.setName("Tag");
tag.addUser(managedUser);
Tag managedTag = em.merge(tag);
//save the id locally
int savedId = managedTag.getId();
//managed tag was sent to UI where its name will be changed to "Changed Tag"
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();

//create another transaction
EntityManager em1 = emf.createEntityManager();
em1.getTransaction().begin();

//simulate a tag sent form UI 
Tag tagFromUI = new Tag();
tagFromUI.setId(savedId);
tagFromUI.setName("Changed Tag");

// I want to associate a new user to this tag
// so create a new user
User newUser = new User();        
newUser.setName("newUser");       
tagFromUI.addUser(newUser);
Tag managedTagFromUI = em1.merge(tagFromUI);


em1.getTransaction().commit();
em1.close();
emf.close();
```

Here is the SQL generated and corresponding explanation

```
//First transaction begins
insert into User (name) values ('User');
insert into Tag (name) values ('Tag');
insert into Tag_User (tags_id, users_id) values (1, 1);
//First transaction ends
//Second transaction begins
// Since a detached tag is merged, hibernate queries for tag id 1 to load it in persistent context
//This tag is associated with a user
select tag0_.id as id1_3_1_, tag0_.name as name2_3_1_, users1_.tags_id as tags_id1_3_3_, user2_.id as users_id2_4_3_, user2_.id as id1_5_0_, user2_.name as name2_5_0_ from Tag tag0_ left outer join Tag_User users1_ on tag0_.id=users1_.tags_id left outer join User user2_ on users1_.users_id=user2_.id where tag0_.id=1;
//copies the state of detached tag from UI to the managed tag and sends update
update Tag set name='Changed Tag' where id=1;
//since merge is cascaded, hibernate looks for the user list of supplied tag and sees an transient User
// the transient instance is merged (created new in  database as it is not yet persisted)
insert into User (name) values ('newUser');
// merge is called on this new managed instance and the resulted instance is set in the managed Tag instance automatically 
//but for this the old relation has to be broken
delete from Tag_User where tags_id=1;
// and the new relation has to be added in database
insert into Tag_User (tags_id, users_id) values (1, 2);
//second transaction ends
```

Comment: my tags class using basic while the user class uses GeneratedValue,so the tag values are fixed,i dont have issues with many to many using a jsf client or java gui client,but since when i started working as with a front end guy doing angular js and sending json objects it totally feels like im a novice. its frustrating. my merge /post operation keeps deleting the roll with related record

Comment: How to achieve this behavior in spring boot ,data rest and jpa application my question is here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111692/unable-to-save-data-to-composite-table-via-spring-data-rest-json-post/43112334?noredirect=1#comment73320408_43112334

Answer (score 0):

while Adding new entries you need to validate that the mappings are not duplicate or already present in the db.For more clarity on the solution plz take a look into my soultion provided in the link

[Relationship table data overwritten in many-to-many hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50071421/relationship-table-data-overwritten-in-many-to-many-hibernate)