# Understanding Hibernate's Session#merge as a Transaction

Tags: java, hibernate

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1070629/409976) gives a solid explanation of `merge` v. `persist` in Hibernate.

Let's say that I'm calling `merge(foo)` in the following example:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
session.merge(foo);
```

Since we don't know what's in `Foo`, this `merge` could result in 1 or more SQL transactions to perform this operation.

For this example, let's say `merge(foo)` results in 3 SQL transactions. If the first 2 transactions succeed, but the third fails, will Hibernate automatically rollback all 3 transactions?

Comment: A call to merge() never results in transactions. You are responsible for starting and committing transactions. The session methods do their work in the current transaction that you have started.

Comment: @JBNizet, do you usually use `@Transactional` in Spring to rollback any commits made if an exception occurred? Thanks

Comment: Yes. Declarative transaction handling is much cleaner, safer and readable than programmatic transaction handling.