# JPA Unique Entries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I want to assign a category to a recipe. If I assign a second category with the same name to the recipe it does another insert to the database that aborts (Abort due to constraint violation (UNIQUE constraint failed: category.name) - this is actually fine). I want to reuse this entry and attach it to the recipe. Is there a JPA way to do this "automatically" or do I have to handle this? Should I search for a category with the same name in the setCategory method and use this one if present? Is there a Pattern?

```
@Entity
public class Recipe {
    private Integer id;
    private Category category;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

} 

@Entity
public class Category {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private List<Recipe> recipes;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    public List<Recipe> getRecipes() {
        return recipes;
    }

    public void setRecipes(List<Recipe> recipes) {
        this.recipes = recipes;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Category category = new Category();
category.setName("Test Category");
cookbookDAO.add(cookbook);

Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
recipe.setTitle("Test Recipe");
recipe.setCategory( category );
recipeDAO.add(recipe);
```

Executing this twice results in the UNIQUE constraint failed: category.name. This is fine since I don't want multiple categories with the same name. The database enforced this but I'm looking for the soltuion to enforce this on the java language level too.
The DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "recipe"
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  category_id INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category(id)
);
CREATE TABLE "category"
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR,
  UNIQUE(`name`) ON CONFLICT ABORT
);
```

Comment: What you need is a collection of category and map them using Hibernate's collection mapping rules. See [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html). In other words, some bits are needed to be done by yourself.

Comment: and "the second category with the same name" comes from where? created from scratch ? (in which case is a different object), retrieved by find()/query() ? in which case represents what is already in the database. Unless you DEFINE your persistence nobody can know. FWIW A JPA "Unique Constraint" is enforced in the DB only ... in DDL

Answer (score 0):

Hello the behavior you are describing is a result of the mapping

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }
```

If we translate this mapping is simple language. You are saying:

> Everytime I attempt to save a Recipe the corresponding Category should
>   be persisted as well.

The problem here comes from the fact that you already have an existing Category so the @Cascade.PERSIST here is not appropriate.

The semantics here is the opposite . A Recipie creates a Category only if a Category does not exist yet. This mean that the creation of the Category is more of an exception than a general rule.

This mean that you have two options here.

**Option 1** is to remove Cascade.PERSIST.

**Option 2** is to replace it with Cascade.MERGE.

**Option 3** is to go the other way. Instead of annotating the @ManyToOne relationship in Recipe to Category  with Cascade.PERSIST to annotate the @OneToMany relationship from the Category to Recipe.

The advantage of such approach is very simple. While you not always want to create a new category when adding a new recipe. It is 100% all the time you want to add a new Category you also want to add all the attached Recipies.

Also I will recommend you to favor Bidirectional relationships over unidirectional ones and read this article about merge and persist [JPA EntityManager: Why use persist() over merge()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are creating a new category with the following statement:

```
Category category = new Category();
```

Because this instance of the `Category` entity is new and accordingly does not have a persistent identity the persistence provider will try to create a new record in the database. As the `name` field of the `category` table is **unique** you get constraint violation exception from the database.

The solution is first fetching the category and assign it to `recipe`. So what you have to do is the following:

```
String queryString = "SELECT c FROM Category c WHERE c.name = :catName";
TypedQuery<Category> query = em.createQuery(queryString, Category.class);
em.setParameter("catName", "Test Category");
Category category = query.getSingleResult();
```

This fetched instance is a managed entity and the persistence provider will not try to save. Then assign this instance to the `recipe` as you already did:

```
recipe.setCategory( category );
```

In this case the cascading will just ignore saving the `category` instance when `recipe` is saved. This is stated in the JPA 2.0 specification in section **3.2.2 Persisting an Entity Instance** as follows:

> If X is a preexisting managed entity, it is ignored by the persist operation.