# difference between entitymanager merge and execute update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What is the difference between `entitymanager.merge` and `query.executeUpdate`.

I have one entity order

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ORDERS",schema ="AMZ")
public class Orders {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "pk_sequence", sequenceName = "ORDERS_SEQ", schema = "AMZ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pk_sequence")
    @Column(name = "ORDERS_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private Status status;
```

I have my DAO class

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class InvoiceDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

public void update(Order order){
updateInvoice();
mergeInvoice(Order order);
}

public void updateInvoice(){
entitymanager.createQuery("update Orders set status = 'ERROR' where id=12").executeUpdate();
}

public void mergeInvoice(Order order){
entitymanager.merge(order);
    }


}
```

In the above, merge happens before `executeUpdate();` even though there are several transactions in between execute update is the last transaction which occurs. WHY?

I tried `entityManager.flush();` but it didn't work.

Comment: post the code calling the mentioned methods.

Comment: Not sure about your code, but your question about `merge` vs. `update`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge  *"Merge creates a new instance of your entity, copies the state from the supplied entity, and makes the new copy managed."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by calling the update and merge methods from service layer.
I found that for the transaction to get commit I have to return out of my DAO.

```
public void update(Order order){
orderDao.updateInvoice();
orderDao.mergeInvoice(Order order);
}
```