# org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist - ManyToMany Mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-security

- I have entity Patient and entity Test.
- Both have ManyToMany relationships each other.
- I added CASCADE_TYPE=ALL at both sides.
- I am using Hibernate EntityManager's persist(Patient); method.
- When i execute it it is throwing "org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: Test"
- These are the screens.

The Patient class
[image: Patient Class - Mapping]

The Test class
[image: Test Class - Mapping]

If anyone have solution please share it.

Thanks.

Comment: try using CascadeType.MERGE

Comment: Please post the code that you have written to persist these objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`merge` and `persist` do pretty different things with your entity. Are you really sure that merge accomplishes what you intended to do in the first place ?
(see [this topic over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge))

Without seeing the code that you wrote to persist the `test` - entity, I can't really tell you what went wrong, but I could imagine it having something to do with the manyToMany-relationships that you have there. Are you sure you want to cascade.ALL ? If you remove a `test`-instance from the database, the cascade will remove every `patient` in that list. 
And then, for every `patient` in that list, it will cascade.REMOVE every `test`
in the `List<test>`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks. i changed it to em.merge() from em.persist(). works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest try to modify `CASCADE_TYPE=PERSIST`.