# Entity with many to many having error in inserting with same ID

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have two entity linked with many to many relationship: Movie and Actor

Movie

```
public class Movie {
    @Id
    private  String imdbId;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = Actor.class)
    private Set<Actor> actor;
}
```

Actor

```
public class Actor {
    @Id
    private  String actorId;
}
```

It is a restful api and I am posting json to MovieController. My json is:

```
{
  "imdbId": "tt2395424",
  "actor" : [{"actorId" : "0001"}, {"actorId" : "0002"}]
}
```

This is working perfectly fine and the actor is populated automatically. But when I insert a new movie with same actorId it throws error that actor is already present. I am confused because as far as I know Hibernate compares the id before insertion if not present it will insert else just map it. Can you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `CascadeType.ALL` above actor set in Movie class. What `CascadeType.ALL` does is perform the same operation on the embedded entities as for parent entity. The save action will try to save the actor in the Actor table, if the actor id is already present in DB then save will throw error. Try to use `saveOrUpdate` instead of `save` operation on movie entity.

Comment: But I am using persist...what is the other alternative to saveOrUpdate when using persist to save?

Comment: You can use merge instead of persist, this is an alternative to saveOrUpdate. Find more details on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge

Comment: Thanks..this works, but any idea about auto-generated ID, because for those I am afraid, it creates duplicate

Comment: I had done some checking before insertion, I think that is only the solution because hibernate doesn't check for auto-generated IDs.