# How to force Hibernate to remove orphans before update

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, constraints, unique

Let's say I have following model structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(....)
public class AnnotationGroup{
    ...
    private List<AnnotationOption> options;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "annotation_group_id", nullable = false)
    public List<AnnotationOption> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(...)
public class AnnotationOption {

    private Long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

At the moment I have `group1` with `AnnotationOption`s `opt1` `opt2` and `opt3`

Then I want to replace all option with only one option `opt1`

[image]

Additionally I have constraint in database:

```
    CONSTRAINT "UQ_ANNOTATION_OPTION_name_annotation_group_id" UNIQUE (annotation_option_name, annotation_group_id)
```

And this one fires:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "UQ_ANNOTATION_OPTION_name_annotation_group_id"
  Detail: Key (name, annotation_group_id)=(opt1, 3) already exists.
```

Actually isuue that hibernate removes orphans after update.

Can you suggest something t resolve issue?

Comment: I have the same problem. May i know how you solved this?

Comment: @J. Adam if I am not mistaken the problem that I recreated collection(assogned new collection to the options field). The correct way is to use old collection(you can dooptions.clear() and then add elements you need)

Answer (score 6):

There are so many things that are wrong in this example:

1. EAGER fetching on the `@OneToMany`collection is [almost always a bad idea](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/).
2. Unidirectional collections are also bad, use the [bidirectional one](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).
3. If you get this exception, most likely you cleared all the elements and re-added back the ones that you want to be retained.

The best way to fix it is to explicitly merge the existing set of children with the incoming ones so that:

1. New child entities are being added to the collection.
2. The child entities that are no longer needed are removed.
3. The child entities matching the business key (`annotation_group_name`, `study_id`) are updated with the incoming data.

Comment: Do you mean over the collection and set ids?

Comment: If you read the articles I provided as links to this answer, you are going to understand why unidirectional collections are bad.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/event/internal/AbstractFlushingEventListener.html) hibernate perform in the following order to preserve foreign-key constraint:

1. Inserts, in the order they were performed
2. Updates
3. Deletion of collection elements
4. Insertion of collection elements
5. Deletes, in the order they were performed

For your special need you should manually flush the transaction to force the deletion in database before.

Comment: I don't do explicit removal. I replace collection

Comment: If by replace you means making a new one don't do that, hibernate use his own implementations of List. To mark all element pf a list as "to delete" in the persistence context use List.clear() instead.