# Spring Jpa Childs are not deleted on parent entity update in OneToMany Relationship

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem updating my entity. As you can see I have three entities.

`LabelValueEntity` holds a list from class `LabelSwitchEntity`.
`LabelSwitchEntity` holds a list from class `SwitchCaseEntity`.

As you can see from my SQL statement the fields `name` and `labelValueUUID` are unique. Only one row of that combination is allowed in my table.

When I update the parent entity (`LabelValueEntity`) with a new list of class `LabelSwitchEntity` I want Hibernate to delete the old list itself and create new entities. It's kinda hard to update the child one by one. That's why I want to delete all the related children directly.

When I update a `LabelValueEntity` and provide it with a list that contains a `LabelSwitchEntity` with a unique name and `labelValueUUID` (Already existing entity in the DB) combination I get a unique constraint violation exception. Well, that error is clear because the combination exists in the DB as I said. I would expect here that Hibernate is smart enough to delete the child before inserting it.

What am I doing wrong?

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "label_value")
class LabelValueEntity(uuid: UUID? = null,
                       ...
                       @OneToMany(
                               mappedBy = "labelValueUUID",
                               cascade = [CascadeType.ALL],
                               fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
                               orphanRemoval = true)
                       @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
                       val labelSwitchEntities: List<LabelSwitchEntity>? = emptyList()
) : BaseEntity(uuid)


@Entity
@Table(name = "label_switch")
class LabelSwitchEntity(uuid: UUID? = null,
                        @Column(name = "label_value_uuid", nullable = false)
                        val labelValueUUID: UUID,
                        @OneToMany(
                                mappedBy = "labelSwitchUUID",
                                cascade = [CascadeType.ALL],
                                fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
                                orphanRemoval = true
                        )
                        val switchCaseEntities: List<SwitchCaseEntity>,
                        @Column
                        val name: String,
                        ...
) : BaseEntity(uuid)

@Entity
@Table(name = "switch_case")
class SwitchCaseEntity(uuid: UUID? = null,
                       ...
                       @Column(name = "label_switch_uuid", nullable = false)
                       val labelSwitchUUID: UUID
) : BaseEntity(uuid)
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE label_switch
(
    uuid UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    label_value_uuid UUID REFERENCES label_value(uuid) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    name CHARACTER VARYING (255) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (label_value_uuid, name)
);

CREATE TABLE switch_case
(
    uuid UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    label_switch_uuid UUID NOT NULL REFERENCES label_switch(uuid) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

BaseEntity

```kotlin
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class BaseEntity(givenId: UUID? = null) : Persistable<UUID> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "uuid", length = 16, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private val uuid: UUID = givenId ?: UUID.randomUUID()

    @Transient
    private var persisted: Boolean = givenId != null

    override fun getId(): UUID = uuid

    @JsonIgnore
    override fun isNew(): Boolean = !persisted

    override fun hashCode(): Int = uuid.hashCode()

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean {
        return when {
            this === other -> true
            other == null -> false
            other !is BaseEntity -> false
            else -> getId() == other.getId()
        }
    }

    @PostPersist
    @PostLoad
    private fun setPersisted() {
        persisted = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214322/how-to-force-hibernate-to-remove-orphans-before-update) the exact same question?

Comment: Just for completeness: What is your `BaseEntity`?

Comment: @MichaelPiefel I added the BaseEntity for completeness

Answer (score 2):

Here is where the transactions come in. If you handle all that logic inside a method annotated with `@Transactional` (be it from `javax` or `spring`), hibernate will do the dirty checking within its bounds, but not validation.

In other words - as long as there is a transaction, hibernate keeps track of changes made to the managed entities, but it does not validate it - it's the responsibility of the database. When being processed in memory, entities are not checked for consistency. Just make sure you're flushing the consistent state to the database (entities at the commit phase of transaction should be consistent).

Other options are possible, when your database allows for it, for example in postgres you can mark the constraints as deferred. When a constraint is defined as `deferred`, it's not checked within an opened transaction, only on commit.

Answer (score 0):

After some struggle i came out with this solution:

```kotlin
fun updateLabelValue(updatedLabelValue: LabelValueDTO): LabelValueDTO {
        val updatedEntity = updatedLabelValue.copy(labelSwitches = emptyList())
        labelValueRepository.saveAndFlush(labelValueMapper.map(updatedEntity))
        val labelValueEntity = labelValueMapper.map(updatedLabelValue)
        return labelValueMapper.map(labelValueRepository.save(labelValueEntity))
    }
```

It's pretty ugly and not really what i wanted. I'm saving the entity first with an empty array so that Hibernate can delete the orphans, after that i do an insert with the updated labelValue with the new orphans.

If you have suggestions or a better solution, drop it down below thanks.

Comment: One better solution would be to not use Hibernate/JPA. JPA makes mapping entities a breeze, but it’s behaviour is often unpredictable for the uninitiated. There are professionals like Vlad who know every detail, but I spent countless hours discussing with colleages about things we could not understand.