# Does EntityManager remove() cause detachment

Tags: jpa

Does calling `EntityManager.remove(someEntity)` -for other than transaction scoped entity manager- cause the entity to be detached? As I was reading the JSR-317 :

> A detached entity results from transaction commit if a
>   transaction-scoped container-managed entity manager is used (see
>   section 3.3); from transaction rollback (see section 3.3.2); from
>   detaching the entity from the persistence context; from clearing the
>   persistence context; from closing an entity manager; or from
>   serializing an entity or otherwise passing an entity by value—e.g., to
>   a separate application tier, through a remote interface, etc.

It didn't mention that `remove()` causes the entity to be detached, though other web sites mentions it. please provide a reference to your answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [JPA 2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) (Section *3.2.3 Removal*, PDF page 82), we find an important piece of information, related to your question:

> After an entity has been removed, its **state** (except for generated state) **will be that** of the entity **at the point at which** the `remove` operation **was called**.

So, the answer seems to be: 
*It depends*.

Yet, on page 80, we find another important bit of information.

> A **removed entity** instance is an instance with a persistent identity, **associated with a persistence context**, that will be removed from the database upon transaction commit.

Thus, we can infer that it is not in a *detached* state as it is still "associated" until finally removed by the TX commit.

Digging deeper, you can consult the [JPA lifecycle image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30168342/2849346) provided in the answer by [Vlad Mihalcea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025118/vlad-mihalcea) to "*understand the JPA state transitions better*". As depicted in the first image (JPA), an entity does not transit to the *detached* state, but ends up in a *removed* state.

Further details on the semantics of the `remove(..)` operation are found on page 81/82 of the JPA Spec document.

Hope it helps.