# What is the difference between em.remove(st) and em.remove(em.contains(st) ? st : em.merge(st));

Tags: java, jpa

I was getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance model.student
```

Then I search for it in stackoverflow and I found this solution:

instead of:

```
em.remove(student);
```

I am using now:

```
em.remove(em.contains(student) ? student : em.merge(student));
```

But I really didn't get why is it working now.

Can someone tell me the diffrence between this methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance com.test.User#5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027398/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-removing-a-detached-instance-com-test-user5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ why is it working now, 
`EntityManager` works only with `ManagedEntities`. When you try to remove an entity which is detached already, you will get an exception.

So to make a safe remove, you have to check first the entity is in managed state or not. that is achieved by `em.contains` method.

And if that entity is not in the managed state yet, we need to manually move that to managed state. This can be achieved by using, [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#merge(T)).

`Merge` basically moves that entity to the managed state.

**[Edit]**

I can see in your code that you've retrieved the entity using **em.find** which would give you an managed entity. But you've not stored that value to anything and used the method's input parameter which is not managed by **em**. Try the following code,

```
`public void deleteStudentsPersistence(Student student) {
    Student managedEntity = em.find(Student.class, student.getId());
    em.remove(managedEntity);
   // em.remove(em.contains(student) ? student : 
   // em.merge(student));
}`
```

Comment: Probably worth to read in the context of this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49214266/2849346

Comment: @DRB how can I do it just with em.remove(student);

Comment: @Mert Yücel, I need your complete code to answer whether that's possible or not..

Comment: @DRB I pushed to Github, you can look from here if you can :) 
 https://github.com/mertowski/NT_JPA_UniPortal

Comment: @Mert Yücel, I've updated the answer . How it helps you!