# JPA: update relationship ManyToOne

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the class `BankDataEntity` that has a relationship `ManyToOne` with `IbanEntity`

```
@Entity
public class BankDataEntity
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumns(value = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_rib", referencedColumnName = "rib", updatable = true),
        @JoinColumn(name = "fk_iban", referencedColumnName = "iban", updatable = true) })
  private IbanEntity ibanEntity;
}
```

I want to update the `BankDataEntity`, so in the below method, i get `BankDataEntity` by id, then i set the new value in `IbanEntity`, then i save `BankDataEntity`.

The problem is that it adds a new IbanEntity in the database instead of modifying the existing one.

```
public void on(BankDataUpdated event) {
  BankDataEntity bankDataEntity = bankDataRepository.findByInternalId(event.internalId);

  IbanEntity currentIban = bankDataEntity.getIbanEntity();
  IbanEntity newIban = currentIban.iban(event.iban).rib(event.rib);
  bankDataRepository.save(bankDataEntity.ibanEntity(newIban));
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA EntityManager: Why use persist() over merge()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/jpa-entitymanager-why-use-persist-over-merge)

Comment: @K.Nicholas Is this a dupe? OP is using Spring repository which is not the same as using EntityManager directly.

Comment: Should lead him in the right direction. This question has been asked and answered so many times here on SO.